# calculating a decrease at constant instantaneous rate

Tags: exponentiation

If we have a value e.g.

$$
B = 20000 
$$

and it decreases at a constant instantaneous rate of say 
$$
-1.1*10^{-2}
$$

per unit time.

What would B look like over say 300 time units, and how do we calculate this decline?

Answer (score 0):

Let B be the function decreasing in time. It is given that

$dB/dt=-1.1*10^{-2}$

Solving this equation gives

$B=-1.1*10^{-2} t+c $ where c is a constant

At t=0 we have B=2000 substituting this in the above equation gives c=2000.

Now substitute t=300 in the equation you will get B = 1996.7

Comment: Given the tag of exponentiation, I wonder if the intent was $dB/dt = -1.1\cdot 10^{-2} \cdot B(t)$. But hard to tell that from the question.

Comment: Yes @Thomas Andrews the title seems to ask about exponential decay but as he describes in the post to be decreasing at a co Stanton rate

Comment: @ThomasAndrews i have this somment in a paper "decreases at a constant instantaneous rate of -1.1 x10^-2" which i assumed to mean a linear straight line decline. But graphs in the paper show what looks like and exponential decline. So i was hoping just from the language of the sentence someone with  better knowledge of nomencalture could explain what they mean

Comment: @user291957 i.e. the % of B left over time looks like an exponential decay, does thins mean it should be `c*t^(−1.1*10^−2)`

Comment: Are there no units in the paper? @user1320502

Comment: Assuming Thomas Andrews is right in his understanding and the title corresponds the equation he has written than the solution of the function is  $B(t)=2000e^{-1.1*10^{-2} t}$